# Negative pending messages in ActiveMQ

Tags: linux, activemq-classic, message-queue, messagebroker

We have a cluster of 6 ActiveMQ nodes. ActiveMQ version is 5.15.8 on all nodes. The problem is that we randomly face negative count of pending messages on brokers. We googled the issue and found that some fellows have the same issue on older versions. But we could not find a proper answer whether the problem has been resolved or not! Does anybody have any updated information about this bug? Is it resolved in upper versions or not?

Comment: How is that a programming question? Asking about the state of some project is not on topic here. Please also read the description of tags you intend to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience, persistent is set to `false` in your ActiveMQ configuration file(activemq.xml):

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" persistent="false">
```

but producers are sending persistent messages.
In case producers send non-persistent messages, this issue will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks man. I'll give it a try. The ecosystem is exactly as you explained.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few edges cases where message counts could go negative. There were various scenarios where this could happen, but it did not mean there was any message loss.

This has been fixed in more recent releases. After your next upgrade (5.17.1 is current), you should not see this any more.

Comment: So is this a bug? For now we cannot upgrade our production servers but we'll have a plan  for upgrade in near future. Is there any way to overcome this issue in this version?

Comment: Running the 'reset statistics' management operation may resolve the counts. The negative counts are usually caused by consumers taking messages (prefetch count) and then only receiving a few before committing a transaction and closing session or connection, causing the other messages to be redelivered by the broker. Be sure your consumers are using PooledConnectionFactory if they are using transactions-- ESPECIALLY with Spring!